# how to convert series integer to datetime in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

i want to convert integer type date to datetime.

ex) i : 20130601000011( 2013-6-1 00:00: 11 )

i don't know exactly how to use pd.to_datetime

please any advice

thanks

ps. my script is below

```
rent_date_raw = pd.Series(1, rent['RENT_DATE'])
return_date_raw = pd.Series(1, rent['RETURN_DATE'])
rent_date = pd.Series([pd.to_datetime(date)
                       for date in rent_date_raw])
daily_rent_ts = rent_date.resample('D', how='count')
monthly_rent_ts = rent_date.resample('M', how='count')
```

Answer (score 3):

Pandas seems to deal with your format fine as long as you convert to string first:

```
import pandas as pd
eg_date = 20130601000011
pd.to_datetime(str(eg_date))
Out[4]: Timestamp('2013-06-01 00:00:11')
```

Your data at the moment is really more of a string than an integer, since it doesn't really represent a single number. Different subparts of the string reflect different aspects of the time.